# Error building UWP package using MS VS 2015 and TACO

Tags: build, uwp, visual-studio-cordova

I use MS VS 2015 Pro edition 14.0 Update 3 and TACO Update 10. I can build any type of Windows package successfully except UWP.  I tried to follow this guide https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-windows-version-of-your-app step by step as well. Always I get these errors:

```
1>  Building project: d:\data\zdroje\PhoneGap\Thurisaz\Thurisaz\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
1>      Configuration : release
1>      Platform      : anycpu
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(170,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.Native.Framework.1.3, Version=1.3". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". [d:\data\zdroje\PhoneGap\Thurisaz\Thurisaz\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(170,5): error MSB3779: The processor architecture of the project being built "Any CPU" is not supported by the referenced SDK "Microsoft.NET.Native.Runtime.1.4, Version=1.4". Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project (in Visual Studio this can be done through the Configuration Manager) to one of the architectures supported by the SDK: "x86, x64, ARM". [d:\data\zdroje\PhoneGap\Thurisaz\Thurisaz\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
1>MDAVSCLI : error C: \Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Please, could anybody let me know, how to solve the issue?

Comment: Please try create a package with processor architecture x86,x64 or arm.

Comment: Yep, it works fine. The only problem is related to UWP.

Comment: Could you please try it with an blank app? If the error persists, please try reinstall windows sdk.

Comment: Blank project is OK - so it's somehow related to the original one. As it's almost empty project - I created it 3 days ago and I just added icons, I can start from scratch again. Thanks.